# Is there a faster way to write this bash directory search for string query?

Tags: bash, unix

Here is something I run on about 32K directories:

```
for f in $*
do
        N=`egrep Ended $f/jobLog.txt | wc -l`
        if [[ $N == 0 ]]
        then
                echo $f
        fi
done > /tmp/repairList
```

It runs, but very slowly - is the a better approach?

I want to list directories where a file called jobLog.txt does NOT contain the string "Ended"

Comment: Well, for a start you could use `-m 1` to tell grep to stop matching after the first match which means it can avoid reading the rest of the file. Then you could drop the new process for `wc -l` and just test $? instead. Then you could use GNU Parallel.

Comment: You could also experiment with `fgrep` as your search string looks pretty `fixed` rather than some fancy extended regex.

Comment: To search recursively in current directory in just one command: `fgrep -L -R --include=jobLog.txt Ended . > /tmp/repairList`

Comment: Not addressing any optimizations, but your script would be better written: `for f; do grep -F -q Ended $f/jobLog.txt || echo $f; done > /tmp/repairList`...and you get a few optimizations for free (fixed string and -q makes grep quit as soon as it finds the string)

Comment: `grep -vl Ended */joblog.txt`? Or if the files are arbitrarily nested - `find . -name joblog.txt -print0 | xargs -0 grep -vl Ended`?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing how your directories and files look and whether you have SSDs or spinning disks, I can't say if this will be faster or not, but it should use all your cores to search in parallel which could be significantly faster:

```
find . -name jobLog.txt | parallel -n 256 -m fgrep -L Ended {}
```

It uses GNU Parallel - [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#name).

Just for fun, I created 32,000 directories and put a file called `jobLog.txt` containing a copy of the Declaration of Independence in each with the word "Ended" added to all except 100 and benchmarked them all. The difference is enormous - see the timings included. 80 seconds versus 1.8 seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash
# METHOD1 - Original
for f in d*
do
        N=`egrep Ended $f/jobLog.txt | wc -l`
        if [[ $N == 0 ]]
        then
                echo $f
        fi
done

real    1m20.178s
user    0m50.072s
sys 1m9.040s

#!/bin/bash
# METHOD2 - use fgrep instead of egrep
for f in d*
do
        N=`fgrep -m1 Ended $f/jobLog.txt | wc -l`
        if [[ $N == 0 ]]
        then
                echo $f
        fi
done

real    1m14.052s
user    0m48.253s
sys 1m5.962s

#!/bin/bash
# METHOD3 - avoid creating 32,000 "wc" processes
for f in d*
do
        fgrep -m1 -q Ended $f/jobLog.txt
        if [[ $? != 0 ]]
        then
              echo $f
        fi
done

real    0m52.412s
user    0m22.542s
sys 0m28.680s

#!/bin/bash
# METHOD4 - Use GNU Parallel
find . -name jobLog.txt | parallel -n 256 -m fgrep -L Ended {} 

real    0m1.850s
user    0m3.211s
sys 0m1.400s
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still summon lots of fgrep processes?

Comment: @konsolebox   Yes, each grep would search 256 files (tuneable), but the point is that if you have 8 cores, there will always be 8 greps running till all files are searched.

Comment: @konsolebox I did some benchmarking for fun... 1.8 seconds versus 1 minute 20 seconds

Comment: I admit you get the point about using `parallal`. I change the negative to positive. Sorry for giving quick judgement. Cheers. If it is applied without `find` and instead using similar concept from mine: (`printf '%s\n' "${@/%//jobLog.txt}"` | ...) perhaps it would be even faster. By the way, it doesn't scramble the lines of the output right? i.e. get the mixed up since they run in parallel.

Comment: @konsolebox No problems. You can add `-k` as a parameter to retain the outoput order when using `parallel` but it doesn't seem necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `fgrep`, `-L` and special expansions:

```
fgrep -L -e Ended -- "${@/%//jobLog.txt}" | sed -e 's|/jobLog.txt||' > /tmp/repairList
```

Perhaps some tool can go faster than `sed` e.g. `awk` or `cut` but that won't give significant gains especially if it's only for 32k lines. The important thing is that you don't call `fgrep` multiple times and that you just let it do the listing instead of running a loop and `echoing` each one of it.

Anyone who'd like to steal the concept can also create a script of Awk that can combine both job of `fgrep` and `sed`.

Comment: Surely you mean `-L` rather than `-l`?